# Keep fvrb-ex's SideBySideExample environment result on single line

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

The `fvrb-ex` package, which uses the `fancyvrb` package, defines a  `SideBySideExample` environment that, according to the documentation, "show the formatted result on the left and the verbatim text on the right. The result is centered vertically according to the text."

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvrb-ex}

\newcommand{\doit}[1]{also {#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{SideBySideExample}
\doit{this}
\end{SideBySideExample}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: SideBySideExample output]

How can one get the entire result of `\doit{this}` on a single line — the same line, in fact, with the verbatim rendering of the command itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set an appropriate `xrightmargin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fvrb-ex}

\newcommand{\doit}[1]{also #1}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule{5cm}{1pt}% For reference

\fvset{xrightmargin=5cm}
\begin{SideBySideExample}
  \doit{this}
\end{SideBySideExample}

\end{document}
```

Note that the default option of `SideBySideExample` (and other examples within `fvrb-ex`) is `gobble=2`, which gobbles the first two characters of each line. Hence the indentation of the code within this environment. Of course, you can also set `gobble=0` to avoid this, if needed.

Comment: Thanks especially for the rule that shows wha `rightmargin` means here.